# Jaxb2marshaller - using contextPath and classesToBeBound

Tags: java

Is this possible?  I have a service that may need to marshal objects from a significant number of projects, each with several object factories.  I currently only specify a few specific classes that need to be marshalled on a regular basis.  Can I add a list of contexts for the other projects, as well as keep my current list of classes?  Or do I have to do one or the other?

With so many individual classes that may need to be marshalled, is it smarter to just simply use a list of contextpaths?

Comment: why you don't iterate over the list and make an instance for each element and do then the marshall stuff?

Comment: Do you mean create a new jaxb2marshaller instance for each item on in list?  There are around 200 classes that would potentially need to be marshalled, and I instantiate the marshaller in Spring.  I was trying to avoid writing out that huge list, and all of the service code is written to use the one marshaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not combine these approaches, it is checked against such usage in `public final void afterPropertiesSet()` in the Jaxb2Marshaller class. However there is in the Spring 3.1 another property that can be used, it is called **packagesToScan**, it accepts wildcards (com.foo.*.schemas), you can also provide a list of such expressions.

But one thing you should know, it doesn't work properly for classes without well known annotation `@XmlRootElement` because of the method `private boolean supportsInternal(Class<?> clazz, boolean checkForXmlRootElement)` in the Jaxb2Marshaller, it will return **false** for elements without this annotation.

Good luck.